# Rename pig tag to apache-pig

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

pig /pig/ noun
noun: pig; plural noun: pigs

1. an omnivorous domesticated hoofed mammal with sparse bristly hair and a flat snout for rooting in the soil, kept for its meat.*
   synonyms:   hog, boar, sow, porker, swine, piglet
2. an oblong mass of iron or lead from a smelting furnace.*
3. platform for analyzing large data sets that consists of a high-level language for expressing data analysis programs, coupled with infrastructure for evaluating these programs.

Problems with the tag: when asking about analyzing some pig epidemic data array the sistem suggest to use the tag. Relevant example: [The pig question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617817/pig-epidemic-java-array)

Solution: Rename to apache-pig to prevent confusion

* Thanks to Google

Comment: Thanks for the definition heh

Comment: A hearty +1, of course! (See [revision 2 of edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22617817/revisions).)

Comment: Fortunately, questions about [tag:fishpig]s and [tag:elephantbird]s seem rare.

Comment: @JasonC I see... developers sucks naming their products :/

Comment: Naming is one of the two hard problems for programmers.  The others are cache invalidation and off by one errors.