# What to do about the [car] tag?

Tags: discussion

There is a [car](/questions/tagged/car) tag which refers to a package under the "R" language. However people use it for problems related to real cars -- the things you drive. What can we do about that?

Comment: Remove the tag from those questions that refer to four-wheeled vehicles (unless, of course, the question is about using the Car package to analyze automobiles).

Comment: Totally relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575, BTW, is "car" such extensive topic that needs a separated tag?

Comment: Please don't remove the `cat` tag, although questions pertaining to real cats tagged such should be migrated to pets.SE

Comment: My other `car` is a `cdr`

Comment: Should we rename it to R-car or something?